# Code-Folding (collapsing) of block comments for Java in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Of all things possible, the most confounding issue with this great IDE is that I can't auto-fold (collapse) a block comment like the following in Java:

```
/*
public String myFunc(){
  doSomething();
}
*/
```

Can someone please enlighten me how to do this?

I've tried googling and rummaging through IntelliJ's docs to no avail...

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I'm using PHPStorm, built on the same engine, and can confirm that this is a problem if the comment is the last thing in the file. If there is any code following the comment block, it seems that the folding works correctly. YMMV.

Comment: I do have code after the block. Interestingly, I just found that if I use continuous line comments... //comment line 1 {newline} //comment line 2 ... I can fold them. But no idea about block comments yet.

Comment: I'm using IJ 14.4 and the closest match I found is using [custom region folding](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/folding-custom-regions-with-line-comments.html)

Comment: Thanks Morfic, but I knew about that already. Looks like there really is no way to "just" fold a block comment...